# Change through list of photos in tab html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

Hi I'm trying to code with HTML CSS and Javascript for my website and I'm not used to these language.

I have "tabs" that was created by css as ul in html, and I wanted to put pictures in them with Javascript linked with image as onclick so I can change through the photos as I clicked them.

here is the code.

**Script function**

```
<script>
    function changeImage(){
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        if(image.src.match("img/test/image1.jpg")){
            image.src = "img/test/image2.jpg";
        }
        else if(image.src.match("img/test/image2.jpg")){
            image.src = "img/test/image3.jpg";
        }
        else if(image.src.match("img/test/image3.jpg")){
            image.src = "img/test/image4.jpg";
        }
        else if(image.src.match("img/test/image4.jpg")){
            image.src = "img/test/image5.jpg";
        }
        else if(image.src.match("img/test/image5.jpg")){
            image.src = "img/test/image1.jpg";
        }
    }
</script>
```

**HTML part**

```
 <div class="tabs">

 <ul class="tab-links">
       <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Kitchenette</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab2">Double Queen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab3">Single Queen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab4">Standard Room</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab5">Partial View Room</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
     <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
        <table style="width:100%">
           <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="img/test/image1.jpg" id="myImage" width="550" height="300" alt="Room Image" onclick="changeImage()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>
                 <p> Description of the room should be in here. </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="img/test/second/image1.jpg" id="myImage" width="550" height="300" alt="Room Image" onclick="changeImage2()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p> Description of the room should be in here. </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
```

**CSS part**

```
/*----- Tabs -----*/
.tabs {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

    /*----- Tab Links -----*/
    /* Clearfix */
    .tab-links:after {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        content:'';
    }

    .tab-links li {
        margin:0px 2px;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
    }

        .tab-links a {
            /*padding:5px 5px;*/
            display:inline-block;
            border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
            background:#7FB5DA;
            font-size:14px;
            font-weight:600;
            color:#4c4c4c;
            transition:all linear 0.15s;
        }

        .tab-links a:hover {
            background:#a7cce5;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

    li.active a, li.active a:hover {
        background:#fff;
        color:#4c4c4c;
    }

    /*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
    .tab-content {
        /*padding:15px;*/
        border-radius:4px;
        box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        background:#fff;
    }

        .tab {
            display:none;
        }

        .tab.active {
            display:block;
        }
```

So the problem I'm having is that the first tab works fine but if I go to the second tab the photo won't change but instead the first tab's photos will be changing.

So I think the onclick reads the click of the second tab's click and just apply it to the first tab but I'm not sure about this..

Please help me... I'm kind of trapped

Comment: Tabs should be created as a single image that you use CSS's `background-position:` property value to move the image. This is the way to do it since some Browsers will create an image flash otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Have your images within the tabs and change the script to look like the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
 
        // Show/Hide Tabs
        $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
 
        // Change/remove current tab to active
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
/*----- Tabs -----*/
.tabs {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
 
    /*----- Tab Links -----*/
    /* Clearfix */
    .tab-links:after {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        content:'';
    }
 
    .tab-links li {
        margin:0px 5px;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
    }
 
        .tab-links a {
            padding:9px 15px;
            display:inline-block;
            border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
            background:#7FB5DA;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:600;
            color:#4c4c4c;
            transition:all linear 0.15s;
        }
 
        .tab-links a:hover {
            background:#a7cce5;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
 
    li.active a, li.active a:hover {
        background:#fff;
        color:#4c4c4c;
    }
 
    /*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
    .tab-content {
        padding:15px;
        border-radius:3px;
        box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        background:#fff;
    }
 
        .tab {
            display:none;
        }
 
        .tab.active {
            display:block;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
       <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Kitchenette</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab2">Double Queen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab3">Single Queen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab4">Standard Room</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab5">Partial View Room</a></li>
    </ul>
 
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <img src="/path/to/img1.jpg" alt="Kitchenette" />
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <img src="/path/to/img2.jpg" alt="Double Queen" />
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <img src="/path/to/img3.jpg" alt="Single Queen" />
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <img src="/path/to/img4.jpg" alt="Standard Room" />
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab5" class="tab">
            <img src="/path/to/img5.jpg" alt="Partial View Room" />
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read  [Element identifiers: the id and class attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) to have a understanding of id and class.

As it says,

> This name must be unique in a document.

you can't make many elements share one id.If you do so, getElementById may only get the first element.

One of methods to address this can be: using different id for each(e.g. myImageTab1, myImageTab2). and adding a class to all image elements if you wants to modify style.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this you can do it with a simple css mouseover.

```css
#tabs {
  border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 365px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs-content {
  padding: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #f2f2f2, #e1e1e1);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f2f2f2), color-stop(100%, #e1e1e1));
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF inset;
}
.tabs a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font: 15px/35px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  padding: 0 20px 0 40px;
  color: #999;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
  border-left: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-right: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs a:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 10px;
  line-height: 21px;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 7px 10px 5px 0;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 21px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 21px;
  border-radius: 21px;
  background: #bdbdbd;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #d4d4d4, #bdbdbd);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d4d4d4), color-stop(100%, #bdbdbd));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #FFF, 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #FFF, 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #FFF, 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tabs a:hover {
  background: #FFF;
  border-left-color: #CCC;
}
.tabs a:hover:after {
  background: #038bd5;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #2dc3fc, #038bd5);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2dc3fc), color-stop(100%, #038bd5));
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #096c9e;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 148, 255, 0.85);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 148, 255, 0.85);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 148, 255, 0.85)
}
.tabs a:hover + .tabs-content {
  display: block;
}
.tabs a:first-child {
  border-left-width: 0;
  display: block;
}
.tabs a:last-child {
  border-right-width: 0;
}
.tabs-content:hover {
  display: block;
}

img{width:550px;
    height:300px;}
```

```html
<div id="content" role="main">

  <div id="tabs">
    <nav class="tabs">
      <a href="#">Kitchenette</a>
      <section class="tabs-content">
        <img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg';" </img>


      </section>
      <a href="#">Double Queen</a>
      <section class="tabs-content">
        <img src="
                       http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/yellowflowers.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg';" </img>
      </section>
      <a href="#">Single Queen</a>
      <section class="tabs-content">
        <img src="
                       http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/mountains.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/purpleflowers.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/mountains.jpg';" </img>
      </section>
      <a href="#">Full View</a>
      <section class="tabs-content">
        <img src="
                       http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/trees.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/trees.jpg';" </img>
      </section><a href="#">Partial View</a>
      <section class="tabs-content">
        <img src="
                       http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/autumntrees.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/trees.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/autumntrees.jpg';" </img>
      </section>
    </nav>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with few lines of j query.

```js
$('#list1 li').click(function() {


  var j = $(this).data("type");

  $('#myimg').attr('src', j);



});
```

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li data-type="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo-10m.svg?v=fc0904eba1b1">Image 1</li>
  <li data-type="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png">Image 2</li>
  <li data-type="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg">Image 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <img id="myimg" src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```